# What tools does Visual Studio provide to easily configure a service?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, service

I have a set of databases that are each collecting data about a different piece of monitored hardware.

I want to write a Windows service which can be run as a blank slate, with no configuration data. I want to be able to add a series of data-retrieval commands for some arbitrary number of servers.

Obviously I can roll my own XML files to store this configuration data, and write a program to read these XML files and allow a user to configure the service to perform these commands, then write code that tells the service to read the XML files and act on the settings, but this all smells of being a solved problem to me...

Is there something within Visual Studio that will allow me to quickly set up "This is my service, this is the service configuration tool, this is the dataset that the service will run and the tool will configure" and which will deploy the tool, the service and the data-file to one common directory?

Or am I over/under thinking it and missing a more obvious solution?

Comment: I wonder why you even need VS. PowerShell has been there for years.

Comment: Need? No. Have existing experience with, knowledge of, and working test code that pulls data from Source A and pushes it to Destination B? Yes.